# How many homomorphisms of fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)\to\mathbb R$ are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

How many homomorphisms of fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)\to\mathbb R$ are there?

I think the answer is 2 because $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2) \simeq\frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{(x^4-2)}$$ and only two root of $x^4-2$ are real (that means that I think also that the number of homomorphisme to $\mathbb C$ is 4).

I'm wrong? I'm not sure to had well wrapped my head around this.

PS: also sorry for my bad English, I'm doing what I can.

Comment: Your English is clear, but I edited your question so that the problem is stated in the main text and not just in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right on both counts.

$
\dfrac{\mathbb Q[x]}{(x^4-2)}
$
can be seen as an *abstract* field containing a root of $x^4-2$, [a construction due to Kronecker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223869/understanding-of-extension-fields-with-kroneckers-thorem).

This field can be written as $\mathbb Q[u]$ with $u^4=2$. It is abstract in the sense that this $u$ does not *want* to be any of the complex roots of $x^4-2$. They are all the same from the algebraic point of view.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)$ can be seen as a concrete realization of $\mathbb Q[u]$ in $\mathbb R$ for instance, in the sense that there is a homomorphism $\mathbb Q[u] \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2)$ that sends $u$ to $\sqrt[4]2$.

If $K$ is a field, then the number of homomorphism $\mathbb Q[u] \to K$ is the number of roots of $x^4-2$ in $K$.

So there are $2$ homomorphisms when $K=\mathbb R$ and $4$ when $K=\mathbb C$.

Note that the number of homomorphism $\mathbb Q[u] \to K$ is *not* necessarily the number of subfields of $K$ that are isomorphic to  $\mathbb Q[u]$.

All this generalizes to $u$ satisfying a polynomial equation $p(x)=0$ with $p \in \mathbb Q[x]$ irreducible.

Comment: So, taking another example, with $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt[6]{2}$ they will be again 2 for the real and 6 for the complex?

Sorry if I bother, you the explanation is clear and nice... just to be sure!

Comment: @DavideF.,yes, 2 and 6.